# Failed to resolve reference “docker.io/hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I’m following this guide: Vault Installation to Google Kubernetes Engine via Helm | Vault - HashiCorp Learn: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-google-cloud-gke

However, after running the Helm install command as below, my vault-agent-injector pod isn’t working as expected.

I ran:

```
helm install vault hashicorp/vault
–set=‘server.ha.enabled=true’
–set=‘server.ha.raft.enabled=true’
```

I then see the following events when describing the pod:

```
Normal Scheduled 51s default-scheduler Successfully assigned default/vault-agent-injector-f59c7f985-n6b72 to gke-test-cluster-test-cluster-np-680d0af5-2lw8
Normal Pulling 51s kubelet Pulling image “hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”
Warning Failed kubelet Failed to pull image “hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image “docker.io/hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”: failed to resolve reference “docker.io/hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hashicorp/vault-k8s/manifests/0.16.1": dial tcp 44.207.51.64:443: i/o timeout
Warning Failed kubelet Error: ErrImagePull
Normal BackOff kubelet Back-off pulling image “hashicorp/vault-k8s:0.16.1”
Warning Failed kubelet Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Normally Helm installs work perfectly fine, so I’m not sure what’s going on here. Could someone please advise?

Comment: This is a networking issue that could have multiple root causes.

Comment: Are you using a Private GKE cluster?

Comment: I am, yes; my Cloud NAT was misconfigured with the wrong VPC name. All confirmed to be working now. Thanks for the help!